# How do I make the shadow of this ::before element go underneath the entire header div?

Tags: html, css, frontend, z-index

I'm horrible with CSS. I'm using React and Styled Components with my project but I managed to recreate the issue in codepen.

I have a fixed header which has a shadow, as well as a circle created by a ::before selector (I have a logo on top in my actual code).

I would like the box-shadow of the circle to go under the header div, so that it looks like one singular shape. Is this possible? I would appreciate any guidance. I tried doing some research on z-index and stacking, but I wasn't able to get anywhere.

Here is a link to a code pen: https://codepen.io/twistedspoon/pen/ExNbrLa

```css
body {
  background: Gainsboro;
  margin: 0;
}

.headerbox {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.6s;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 24px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}

.logobox {}

.logobox::before {
  transition: none;
  margin: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  transform: translateY(30%);
  bottom: 0px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 24px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerbox">
  <p>some title text</p>
  <div class="logobox"></div>
  <div>
    <a>a link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all box-shadows and try this:

```
.headerbox {
 filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45));
}
```

```css
body {
  background: Gainsboro;
  margin: 0;
}

.headerbox {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.6s;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45));
}

.logobox {}

.logobox::before {
  transition: none;
  margin: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  transform: translateY(30%);
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerbox">
  <p>some title text</p>
  <div class="logobox"></div>
  <div>
    <a>a link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```